# We need a better tour question

Tags: discussion, status-completed

I was just inspired to review our [Tour](https://ham.stackexchange.com/tour) page, and I find the question that's there ([Why is the 70cm band commonly referred to as the 432MHz band?](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/1099/why-is-the-70cm-band-commonly-referred-to-as-the-432mhz-band)) to not be a great choice. It's a question about the reason for a piece of jargon, and therefore invites speculative and this-is-how-I-learned-it answers.

I propose that we replace it with a highly-voted, practical, technical question.

Unfortunately, the question and answer [have to be short and plain](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163947/what-determines-the-questions-available-for-selection-in-the-about-page). And this means that all of our best questions, such as the ones I've highlighted below as otherwise great questions on our site, aren't available.

- [How do I report an emergency using ham radio?](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/59/how-do-i-report-an-emergency-using-ham-radio)
- [What is the relationship between SWR and receive performance?](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/382/what-is-the-relationship-between-swr-and-receive-performance)
- [Why do concurrent FM signals not mix together?](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/337/why-do-concurrent-fm-signals-not-mix-together)
- [I hate contests. How can I avoid them?](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/1132/i-hate-contests-how-can-i-avoid-them)

Any suggestions about what to do? **Is there an existing question which could be nudged into meeting the requirements?** (I just went through all of our score=4 questions and voted as I saw fit, but few of those meet the 2-short-answers criterion.)

[Here is a Data Explorer query which lists questions that *almost* meet the criteria.](http://data.stackexchange.com/ham/query/342500/possible-tour-questions-and-near-misses) They could be made to meet it by adding one or more of: upvotes, tags, comments, or a *second* short-and-plain answer.

(Another part of the tour that is open for per-site editing is the “Ask about…” and “Don't ask about…” lists further down. I'd also like to hear about improvements there.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hurrah!

New questions have become eligible, and we now have a better question in the tour:

**[Are there ways for people with receivers to participate in contests?](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/1134/are-there-ways-for-people-with-receivers-to-participate-in-contests)**

It's not a Perfect Specimen of a SE Question, but it's more practical and less subjective than the old question. I'm happy.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a few options:

- [How do sunspot numbers (SSN) affect radio operations?](https://ham.stackexchange.com/q/751/13)
- [How to mark SWL contacts on eQSL?](https://ham.stackexchange.com/q/1649/13)

Of these, I would think the first would be the best option, as it's a decent question, with a few good short answers.

Comment: Other than votes: The SSN Q is ineligible because the longer answer is twice as long as the limit. (This _could_ be fixed by making up another short answer.) The SWL Q is ineligible because it has monospace. (This could be fixed by formatting it some other way, but that seems wrong.)

Comment: Wow, the limit is really short... That could be tricky. Hmmm...

Comment: (Note: Even though I proposed “fixes”, I'd really like to get _almost-entirely-natural_ better content in the tour page.)

Answer (score 0):

(Just making notes for now...)

[How do club codes stay secret?](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/467/how-do-club-codes-stay-secret) is a near miss; it seems decent, has no extra formatting, but both the question and one of the answers are a bit over the 400 character limit.

[How can I prevent my mobile radio from draining my vehicle's battery?](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/301/how-can-i-prevent-my-mobile-radio-from-draining-my-vehicles-battery) is perfectly eligible — except there's another requirement I missed before: there must be a *comment* on one of the answers. Great. How do you *add* a comment on something that doesn't need to be changed, that's not a bad example?